# Locus of points on a rotating line

Tags: geometry

A line rotates about a fixed point $O$ with ordered  points O,P,and M moving along the line.

Find locus of points P and M if $ OM^2 - MP^2 = T^2 $ constant for all inclinations of $OP$.

The geometrical result seems (to me) equally significant as the Pythagorean theorem:

EDIT1:

Tau iso-surfaces are loci of P.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates#/media/File:Bipolar_tau_isosurfaces.png

The Apollonius circles are drawn for the invariant T = 1.

Comment: I don't think I'm reading this correctly so you might need to clarify it. If $O$, $P$, $M$ and $Q$ are on the line you the points trace three circles centered at $O$ with radius the length of $OP$, $OM$ and $OQ$ respectively. The relation of the lengths of their radii is of little consequence but it most certainly is constant all along.

Comment: Apologies. Realizing the same, I changed it a bit as above, moving points M and P. Hope OK now.

Comment: With this edit, we still have a problem.  We can freely move $P$ and that would define the movement on $M$. However we can move $P$ rather randomly. For example I can move it linearly away from $O$ or I can chose to move it to and fro so as the line rotates. This isn't thought through.

Comment: Please see edit for a hint.of midpoint M.

Comment: @ Mr. P   Yes, $OP$ can be unbounded.along this line.

Comment: @Narasimham: You clearly want to characterize tau isosurfaces as loci, but your relation isn't quite the way to do it. As Mr.P notes, for any particular $P$ and $M$ (collinear with $O$) that satisfying your relation, *all the rotations of these points* about $O$ (by the same angle) also satisfy the relation. Therefore, "the locUS" of $P$ is the union of the various $P$ circles; and "the locUS" of $M$ is the union of the various $M$ circles. (Respectively, the interior and exterior of the circle of radius $T$ about $O$.) [continued]

Comment: [continued] It's certainly *interesting* that the $P$ and $M$ loci can be decomposed into pieces of isosurfaces. Pick a line $\ell$ through $O$, and the $P$ locus partitions into arcs of circles, with centers on $\ell$, orthogonal to the radius $T$ circle; the $M$ locus partitions into arcs of circles with centers on $\ell$, tangent to the the perpendicular to $\ell$ at $O$. However, your description lacks a reason to think of this as "the" way to view the loci. You may be trying too hard to turn a property of circles into a way of magically generating a particular set of circles.

Comment: I tried demonstrating validity of assumption with the result. Any more heuristics are needed?

Comment: There is some spillover into a related topic                     http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402155/property-of-circle-tangent-and-intercepts

Answer (score 0):

*General* formula derivation for circles in the plane.

$ u = r\,\sin \psi$ is the Clairaut invariant for geodesics in $\mathbb R ^2$ 
and in particular, the plane. If $s$ is arc length by differential geometry it can be checked by differentiation that:

$$\dfrac{d u}{d s}  = \frac{r\,\sin \psi}{ds} = r\,\cos \psi \cdot k_g , \tag{1}$$

by virtue of Liouville's curvature Formula for polar symmetric curves.As

$$ \dfrac{d r}{d s} = \cos \psi \tag{2}$$ for differentials, we have the *identity* relation for curvature:

$$\dfrac{d u}{r d r} ==   k_g. \tag{3}$$

For a of *constant* radius $a$ or curvature $k_g=1/a$ we have

$$\dfrac{d u}{r d r}  = =   1/a \tag{4}$$ which integrates to

$$  u= \dfrac{r^2}{2\,a} + C_1 ; $$ With boundary condition $$ \psi=0, u=0,  r = T \tag {5} $$ or

$$ 2 a u = r^2-T^2  \tag {6}$$ i.e.,

$$ r^2 - 2 a r\,\sin \psi-T^2  =0 \tag {7} $$

Or, using the sketch alongside

$$ r(r - 2 a \sin \psi)  =T^2 \tag {8} $$

It is seen as the differential equation of *an eccentric* circle.

Now we can read these lengths as line segments :
[image: RotatingLine]

$$ r = OP ,\, (r - 2 a \sin \psi) = OQ $$

$$ OP \cdot OQ = (OM-MQ)(OM+MQ)= (OM^2-MQ^2)  = T^2 \tag{9}$$

We are given the last relation

$$ (OM^2-MQ^2)  = T^2 \tag{10} $$

When the variable inclination line rotates with movable points $ Q,M,P $ the above assumption is valid for all circles of arbitrary radius $a$, constant power $T^2$, centered at a variable distance of $h$.

The assumed condition of difference of squares of two collinear connected segments being constant is found to be agreeing with the same result obtained.

$$ OC= h = \sqrt {a ^2+ T^2}.  \tag{11}$$

The single red line shown is orthogonal to this set, which is known as $ \tau $ surfaces in bipolar coordinates.

A single $\tau$ circle or Apollonius Circle is associated with any pair of connected collinear line segments.

EDIT1:

If Line $OQP$ and direction of tangent $ OT$ is given, mark off length $T$ from $O$ at $T$ on $OT$. By Apollonius PPL method a unique tangent can be constructed using ruler and compass.

EDIT2:

We can express ***the single curve*** viz., a circle in Cartesian coordinates using  *two* arbitrary parameters *(a,t)* brought in as above. It holds *upto  a rotation, polar coordinate t *

It is a set of circles of radius $a$ shifted along x-axis to have the constant power $T^2$.

$$ x = \sqrt{T^2 + a^2} + a \cos t, y = a \sin t   \tag{12}$$

Parameterization of $\tau $ circles in Mathematica and its plot given below:

> T = 1; ParametricPlot[{Sqrt[T^2 + a^2] + a Cos[t], a Sin[t]}, {a, 1.4,
>   4}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> {5, 29},   PlotStyle -> {Yellow,
>   Opacity[.5]}, PlotLabel -> Tau_surf]

[ApolloniusPPL](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401662/triangle-construction-procedure)

[image]

[image: RotCircTgtXaxis]

wlog , as the equations are freely rotatable about $O$, all the circles of unit power can be rotated to be tangential to x-axis at (1,0) with constant (= unity) as segments product.

$$ (x-1)^2 + y\, ( y- 2\, k) = 0   \tag{13} $$