# Property of Circle Tangent and Intercepts

Tags: geometry

Is there a proof for *Inverse* theorem of following well known property of circles among Euclid's Elements?

A line  $OQP$ rotates  about fixed point $O$ such that $ ( OP\cdot OQ )$ is a constant. Show that $Q$ and $P$ share the same circle locus.

Comment: If the constant is $1$, then how do you rule-out the circles of radius $p=2$ & $q=1/2$ about $O$? (Every point $P$ on the $p$-circle has a counterpart $Q$ on the $q$-circle such that $Q$ is between $O$ & $P$, the relation $OP\cdot OQ = 1$ holds, and yet the $p$-circle & $q$-circle are not "the same circle locus".) This kind of situation is the *fundamental flaw* in all of your recent attempts to invert the power-of-a-point property into simple conditions that define specific families of circular loci. Your goals are clear (and respectable!), but your formulations require some adjustment.

Comment: @Blue  Please move this comment to : * Locus of points on a rotating line* for an answer. Regards

Comment: My comment addresses this question directly, so I'll leave it here. I've seen your answer to the previous question, but it does not resolve the problem inherent in your locus formulations. There, here, and elsewhere, your "locus of $P$" is actually a **region of the plane**. You've shown that such a region *can be* covered by (arcs of) certain special circles ---which is great--- but that's very different from saying that those circles "are" the locus, as if the "$OP\cdot OQ = \text{constant}$" relation leads inevitably to them. (The $p$ & $q$ circles I mentioned above contradict this notion.)

Comment: @ Blue http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398614/locus-of-points-on-a-rotating-line. The p-circle or q-circle are *not different!* There is *one and only one*  circle that passes through $P$ and $Q!$.  The $ P$  part of the circle is just the inversion of the second  $Q$ part! They are governed by a * single * differential equation already given. And also the  *unique* parametric form of this  *single circle* is given.. Also the entire circle  can be rotated  about $O$  as it is a constant of integration in ax-symmetric polar coordinate situation.

Comment: contd.. The locus  (locUS) is a continuous Jordan curve, just an eccentric circle.I am  unable to guess any need for any further adjustments  seen to be needed to determine a simple circle. :

Comment: My $p$-circle has radius $2$, the $q$-circle has radius $1/2$. These, my friend, are *not* the same circle! ;) Look: take $P = 2\;(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ and $Q = 1/2\;(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, with $O$ at the origin. For every $\theta$ (aka, "for all inclinations of the line"), we have the order $OQP$, & the constant $|OP|\cdot |OQ| = 2\cdot (1/2) = 1$. *From your description*, these circles provide valid loci for $P$ & $Q$. I know that you *want* the solution to be only the far-more-interesting inversive one, but your formulation *allows* my uninteresting one. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: I don't chat, so I'll leave a final thought here: I'm rooting for you. The Power of a Point is a favorite tool of mine, and I'd *like* to see you succeed at flipping it on its head. To do it right, though, you may have to be so specific as to give away too much of the magic in the setup, as in: "If, for collinear $O$, $P$, $Q$, we have $|OP|\cdot |OQ| = k$ (taking $k<0$ when $O$ separates $P$ and $Q$), **and if $P$ traces some circle** (center $C$, radius $r$), **then $Q$ traces some (other) circle**; in particular, if $k = |OC|^2 - r^2$ (w/caveat when $|OC|=r$), then the two circles match."

Comment: @Blue  :), now you are slowly veering around to the point and I trust you would eventually see it.These are the other  iso- $\sigma $ surfaces. Previously it is from an external point, now these are a set of lines through a point $O$ inside the circle. The maths is $ exactly$  the same,    except that $ T^2 \rightarrow -T^2 = k $. Each  semi-chord through $O$  is of length $ \pm \sqrt{ |k|} . $

Comment: I'm well aware of the geometry of the circle families you've been trying to characterize. I've been hoping that *you* would see that your formulations in terms of the $OP\cdot OQ = k$ relation have been wholly *inadequate* to define those families. Again, your description above *allows* my $p$ and $q$ circles (which are *not* in either the $\tau$ or $\sigma$ iso-surface family), because it allows for arbitrary rotations of a particular $P$-&-$Q$ solution pair. My formulation avoids the rotations by introducing a preferred direction ($OC$). That's the kind of fix you need. Good luck; I'm done.